# Chebyshev function identity

Tags: number-theory

given the Chebyshev function

$$ \sum_{n \le x} \Lambda (n) = \Psi (x) $$

with $$ \Lambda (n) = \log p $$ for $ n=p^{k} $ and $ 0 $ otherwise

is then true that (i think i saw it in apostol book)

$$ \Psi(x) + \Psi(x/2) + \Psi (x/3)+ \ldots = \log\lfloor{x!}\rfloor $$

here $ x! $ stands for factorial of '$x$'

in case the result is incorrect , what would be the correct result ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should follow from the fundamental theorem of arithmetic. The fundamental theorem of arithmetic is encoded by the von Mangoldt function:

http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Sum_Over_Divisors_of_von_Mangoldt_is_Logarithm

Or with the terms exponentiated as in this oeis table:
http://oeis.org/A140256

Taking partial products in the vertical direction we get this oeis table:
http://oeis.org/A139547

which is the same as:

$$\Psi(x) + \Psi(x/2) + \Psi (x/3)+ \ldots = \log\lfloor{x!}\rfloor$$