# Expressing $\log(\left \lfloor x \right \rfloor!)$ in terms of zeta-zeros

Tags: number-theory, riemann-zeta

Let $\psi(x)$ be the second Chebyshev Function. By the definition of this summatory function, and the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, we have the [identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/262110/chebyshev-function-identity):
$$\log(\left \lfloor x \right \rfloor!)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\psi\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)$$

Is there a way to utilize the well-known explicit formula

$$\psi(x)=x-\sum_{\rho}\frac{x^{\rho}}{\rho}-\log(2\pi)-\frac{1}{2}\log\left(1-x^{-2}\right)\qquad\zeta(\rho)=0\;(0<\Re(\rho)<1)$$
to express $\log(\left \lfloor x \right \rfloor!)$ in terms of zeta-zeros $\rho$?

Please notice that $\psi\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)=0$ for $n>\frac{x}{2}$. Thus, the summation might be truncated at $\left \lfloor \frac{x}{2} \right \rfloor$.

*Now posted on Mathoverflow:* https://mathoverflow.net/questions/149932/expressing-log-left-lfloor-x-right-rfloor-in-terms-of-zeta-zeros?rq=1

Comment: Apart from substituting your second formula into the first, you mean? I suspect this isn't a route to understanding much, because in a naive expansion the four terms of the explicit formula for $\psi$ would give you four divergent series in the expression for $\log (\lfloor x \rfloor ! )$; and the role of the zeta-zeros is pretty well obscured by the need to balance all the series to reach a finite sum. A further problem is that $(1 - (x/n)^{-2})$ is negative when $n$ is large, for any real $x$, so you will meet issues over the complex logarithm.

Comment: I agree with HTFB. At the very least you should manually truncate the sum at $n=(\log x)/\log 2$. The resulting formula will be valid but, I suspect, unenlightening.